# Unique observations per column

Tags: r

In

```
data <- structure(list(A = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), B = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L), C = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), D = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

where columns are samples, and rows are species observations.

How can i obtain the number of species that only appear in a single column ( or a subset of the dataframe?

In this example, species 5 is exclusively occuring in sample A, and species 2 in sample D. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rowSums(data) == 1
```

Gives you the species that appear only in one column.

**Update**

Gives you the columns where the singletons appeared:

```
colSums(data[rowSums(data) == 1, ]) == 1
```

Comment: Thank you, but how is it possible to obtain the information in which column the singleton appeared?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could try:

```
 data[!rowSums(data) > 1,]
 #  A B C D
 #2 0 0 0 1
 #5 1 0 0 0
```

This will get you only rows 2 and 5, as species 2 occurs only in sample D, and 5 as occurs only in sample A.